# Unable to open Qiskit Assignments for Qiskit 2023. (Quantum Challenge 2023)

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

Unable to open Qiskit Assignments for Qiskit 2023. (Quantum Challenge 2023)

I was very excited to be a part of Qi skit 2023. I went through all the lectures in the crowd cast, but now I am very upset as I am unable to complete the assignments. The Assignments are still not open for me. I want to provide bad feedback.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: That, you are "Unable to open Qiskit Assignments for Qiskit 2023. (Quantum Challenge 2023)" and you want to know how?

Comment: Is it to do with this: @ https://github.com/qiskit-community/ibm-quantum-challenge-spring-2023  and @  https://qiskit.org/events/summer-school-2023   ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.